How do I create an SSL certificate on a website hosted on a Mac OS Sonoma system using a third-party SSL provider?
We have a website that we are hosting from a MacBook. We are looking to add an SSL certificate to the website itself. How do we do add the SSL certificate to the website?
We originally had this website hosted on another, older iMac, running an outdated OS, and it was compromised, and we believe through the website.
I am in the researching phase so far and looking up as much information as possible regarding how to do this. I have found that we can create a local (self-assigned) certificate to the entire system via the terminal, but I am unsure if this will also cover a hosted website. We also have access to third party SSL certificates and would like to assign one to the hosted website.
Any constructive advice and help would be very much appreciated.

Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage (or server setup); Superuser is a better place for things like this. But really, it mostly depends on the server software you're using (e.g. Apache vs nginx vs... ?), so the first place to look is that software's documentation. As for getting the cert, if you want the site to be accessible by other people, you need to get a cert from a trusted certificate authority; you cannot make it yourself.

Hi Gordon, From the name, I suspected that that site offered support for coding, but I am reaching out to any source to try and figure out our issue. Thank you for suggesting "SuperUser," I'll repost there.
